# Progress database administrator password recovery or reset

Tags: database, password-recovery, progress-db

A client of mine have a progress 7.3 database. The company that made the system is out of business, and he wants to export the data to text files.
However, the company did not give him the admin password. 
The question is: how can we reset/recover the password of a Progress database?
Thanks

Comment: I used to work with Progress 8.1 but that was many years ago it won't be easy to get an answer... even here

Answer (score 1):

It would be unusual for a Progress 7.3 database to actually have an administrator password.

Is there an actual error message?

If he's just being prompted for a username & password on login press the cancel button or  on Windows, ^E on UNIX.  That will probably let him in as a "blank" user which in many cases will be sufficiently privileged to dump the data.